# How to define a method for the class 'Proxy' in Dart js-interop?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm currently calling a jQuery based plugin called [Bootstrap Context Menu](https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu).

In order to call it, I need to use the [Javascript Interop library](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js). But when I call a jQuery method from it I receive the following warning:

```
The method 'jQuery' is not defined for the class 'Proxy'
```

Code snippet:

```dart
  js.scoped(() {
    js.context.jQuery('#canvas').contextmenu();
  });
```

This was not happening before some dart/js-interop updates. What is the right way to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this warning because the new analyzer doesn't seem to be aware of the option *Report 'no such member' warnings when class defines noSuchMethod()* ( Reported at http://dartbug.com/10016 ). If you switch back to the *legacy analyzer* you shouldn't see this warning anymore.

That said if you want to use the new analyzer and get rid of this warning you can use the array notation like this :

```dart
js.context["jQuery"]('#canvas')["contextmenu"]();
```

But :

- it's less readable particullary for method calls.
- it's less efficient for method calls because 2 operations are done ( `f = js.context["jQuery"]` followed by `f('#canvas')` ) instead of 1 ( `js.context.jQuery('#canvas')` )

Comment: Thanks, should we open a new Issue in dartbug then? I agree with you, it makes code less readable and efficient.

Comment: Yes, a new issue should be opened. It's less efficient for method but not for attributes (~10% faster). The array notation has however some advantages : it makes smaller code with _dart2xxx_ and it works with _--minify_ - see http://dartbug.com/9283 .

Comment: Two questions about this answer.  First, why use single and double quotes in the example?  Does it work the same with all double quotes or all single quotes?  Second, now that there is "dart:js", what is the preferred way to call jQuery from Dart?  Thank you.

Comment: 1/ There's no difference between single and double quotes in Dart.
2/ It depends. If the code size don't matter, _package:js_ provides a cleaner API ( `js.context.jQuery('#canvas').contextMenu()` vs `js.context.callMethod('jQuery', ['#canvas']).callMethod('contextmenu')` with _dart:js_)